# Git for Windows "No tags file" Response from "git diff" Command

Tags: windows, git, msbuild, atlassian-sourcetree, git-diff

Git version: 2.14.2.2

Whenever I run `git diff` on a repository I am greeted with the response `No tags file`. I have tried running the command on multiple repositories, multiple consoles (Cmd, PowerShell, MINGW64, Visual Studio Command Prompt) and all have the same response.

[image: No tags file]

Strangely, the `git log` command also fails. Many other commands work, however, such as `git status`, `git pull`, etc.  It seems to be only `log` and `diff`.

[image: Working commands]

I have uninstalled Git entirely and reinstalled.  Restarted my system. Tried referencing the `git.exe` directly (which yields the exact same response).  Nothing is working and I have not seen this error anywhere else. I compared my user configs with those of a colleague and they are identical.

*Some portion* of the command executes properly, because if I supply two commit hashes, and I intentionally break one, the response I receive is:

[image: Bad Response]

It seems like another program may be hijacking the `git diff` command. I believe this because I'm not sure "No tags file" is even a possible Git response.  Not sure what else it would be.

To make things even more confusing- my ultimate goal is to run the `git diff` within the context of an `msbuild` and it DOES EXECUTE CORRECTLY. Now, I could be satisfied with this, but I need to modify the `diff` command slightly, and running a full build each time is not productive, nor easy to troubleshoot. There is a task within the build script that runs an `Exec` command and it has no issues performing the `diff`.  I'm also able to execute a `Diff Against Current` within SourceTree, which to the best of my knowledge, runs a `git diff` behind the scenes.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**:: Edits ::**

Various commands:

```
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD
git diff master~1 master
git diff <commit-hash-1> <commit-hash-2>
git log HEAD~1..HEAD
git log master~1..master
git log <commit-hash-1>..<commit-hash-2>
```

Output:

Every one of the commands above returns the same `No tags file` response, in all of my repos.

Cat Head:

```
cd .git
cat HEAD
ls -R refs
```

Output:

[image: CatHead]

New Repo:

```
mkdir testrepo
cd testrepo
git init
echo "file1" > file1.txt
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit of file1.txt"
echo "Hi there!" > file2.txt
git add .
git commit -m "added file2.txt"
git log
git diff HEAD~1 HEAD
```

Output:

[image: NewRepo]

git config -e:

[image: gitconfige]

git config --global -e:

[image: gitconfigglobale]

**::Edits 2::**

I uninstalled all of my diffing/source control tools (SourceTree, Git, SVN, WinMerge, KDiff).  Installed the portable version of Git.  Opened CMD to a repo, put in full path to the git.exe portable and it still returned the `No tags file` response.

I also reviewed all of my path variables for: git, vim, ming, mintty and anything else that seemed suspect, but didn't find any.

I have restarted after performing all steps, and yet the problem persists.

**::Edits 3::**

I have a different user on my laptop, switched to that user and the `git diff` works properly, so clearly there is something with my main user that is conflicting.  Will continue to look into my `User` directory for issues.

Comment: Have you tried `git diff HEAD`?

Comment: @jrap After thinking about this a bit with your edits - I'm really curious how your tools can do a diff or log.  What directory do you have git installed to, and are those tools using that same directory?  It's almost like they are using a different one.  You may want to try installing Git Extensions and see if it can do diffs - I know it uses an installed Git folder - in fact, you have to point it to the folder (normally).

Comment: When googling for the "No tags file" message, the first results I get talk about `vi`. I do not understand why `git` would try to execute `vi` when running `git diff` or `git log`, could it be that your system is configured to use `vi` as a pager ?

Comment: Confirmation that the error message I'm seeing is being output by `less.exe`: https://github.com/vbwagner/less/blob/master/tags.c, but not sure what this means.

Comment: If you are exclusively running everything in powershell, well, that shouldn't be an issue, but might be something another tool has setup that is leaking into that shell.  Like LeGEC mentions, try the Git Bash directly (just do a start button/Cortana search on Git and it should pop up).  Also, can try a straight command window instead of power shell (Git Cmd should also do this from the search).

Comment: I've tried a mixture of Powershell/CMD/Bash.  Same issue persists in all.  Issue appears to be related to Less.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I'd take in this situation:

1. Try the following and check the response:

   > ```
   > git diff HEAD~1 HEAD
   > git diff master~1 master
   > git diff <commit-hash-1> <commit-hash-2>
   > ```
2. Try the same with log:

   > ```
   > git log HEAD~1..HEAD
   > git log master~1..master
   > git log <commit-hash-1>..<commit-hash-2>
   > ```

   I'm actually guessing that your refs are messed up, which means that the direct hashes might work, but the `HEAD` and/or `master` one may not.
3. Look into the `.git/refs` folder

   From the main repo folder:

   > ```
   > cd .git
   > cat HEAD
   > ls -R refs
   > ```

   Hopefully, `HEAD` is pointing to a branch, and if `master` is checked out, `cat HEAD` output should look like:

   > ```
   > ref: refs/heads/master
   > ```

   Then, the `ls -R refs`, should show a `heads` folder, with files for each of your local branches (i.e. `master` and possibly others).  You also likely have `refs/remotes` and `refs/tags` directories.

   If any of these things are radically different or missing, that could be your issue...
4. Since you have reinstalled git, create a brand new repo and try the same commands:

   > ```
   > mkdir testrepo
   > cd testrepo
   > git init
   > echo "file1" > file1.txt
   > git add .
   > git commit -m "initial commit of file1.txt"
   > echo "Hi there!" > file2.txt
   > git add .
   > git commit -m "added file2.txt"
   > git log
   > git diff HEAD~1 HEAD
   > ```

   If this last one works, then git is likely working okay, but some tool you have is messing things up.
5. Post your config from `git config -e` and `git config --global -e` - maybe we can see something?

Comment: I have updated my question with the output from everything that you've asked.. Still no luck, but hopefully more information to assist.

Comment: Wow, this gets weirder and weirder - even the new repo gives the same `No tags file` response for log and diff.  Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with Sourcetree as a tool, but I'd start looking there or with any other tools you have installed.  I'd might even go so far as to uninstall everything SCM and Git related and try a fresh install of Git and retry a test repo with just that.

Comment: Running out of ideas quickly. I tried on the test repo you had me create, with the portable exe and I still got the same response.  I also reviewed my `%LOCALAPPDATA%` directory for anything suspect, but didn't find anything obvious.

Comment: Take one of your cloned repos, and move it (the entire directory) to a PC that has no issues, and see if their Git run into the same problem (you can do this directly from a USB or network share - no need to even put it on the other PC directly).  If they have issues with diff as well, then it's a problem in the repo itself, not your Git install.  If they also have a problem, it proves your tools are somehow corrupting your Git repos.  Still doesn't explain why your tools can do a diff and commandline Git cannot.

Comment: Per latest edits, I simply switched users on my PC and git works correctly.  I'm in the process of reviewing my `AppData` folder for anything that looks off.. so far no luck.

Comment: It's got to be a piece of software that is mucking with your shell environment...

Answer (score 3):

When googling for the "No tags file" message, the first results I get all talk about `vi`.

I do not understand why `git` would try to execute `vi` when running `git diff` or `git log`, could it be that your system is configured to use `vi` as a pager ?

```
# some possible places which could influence that :
echo $PAGER
echo $GIT_PAGER
git config --get core.pager
```

---

When digging in the documentation for `less`, I found that `less` can use a `ctags` file, to spot "the file that contains this tag".

So you can also look at the list of variables that influence the behavior of `less` :

```
# from bash :

# env will list all the defined environment variables
env

# the ones that impact 'less' should contain "LESS" in their names :
env | grep LESS
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to be anything useful.  Log here: https://www.screencast.com/t/l31mPF7Peg4

Comment: @jrap : you ran it from a Windows cmd.exe shell. Try it from `git bash` (the same from where you run `git diff` or `git log`)

Comment: However, this works properly: `C:\Projects\Git\PortableGit\bin\git --no-pager diff HEAD~1 HEAD`

Comment: So it DOES appear it's using some type of pager. Interestingly, I see execution of `less.exe` with reference to `repo\tags` with failed attempts. I saw this output using Windows Process Monitor. https://www.screencast.com/t/HzJkdIlrp32y

Comment: The above output was after viewing Process Monitor while executing `git diff` and filtering on `git/NewRepo`... in other words, this command fired `less.exe` behind the scenes and it failed to find a tags file.

Comment: Doesn't let me award bounty yet, but @LeGEC you're the winner. Per https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#__code_core_pager_code, I changed the pager to `more` and it now works properly. Now- something was/is certainly up with my `less`, but I have a solution that works and will not waste any more time on this.

Comment: you were correct with your edit.  I had an environment variable `LESS=true`. I was using it in one of our projects as a key. As soon as I removed this variable and restarted BASH it worked.